# Check custom attribute value in transactional order email

Tags: php, template, transactional-mail

I want to display a specific code in the order email, when a product attribute got the value yes.

Therefore I add the following code to my **transactional** e-mail:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/delivery.phtml' order=$order}}
```

In the specific **email/order/delivery.phtml** template I added the following code:

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>

<?php if ($this->escapeHtml($_item->getProduct()->getDates())== "Yes"): ?>
    <td class="method-info">
        <h6>Dates</h6>
        Yes
    </td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But sadly that does not work, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $productId = $_item->getProduct()->getId(); ?>
<?php $product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); ?>
<?php $_order    = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($product->getDates()) == "Yes"): ?> // check if you have well your dates attribute
<td class="method-info">
    <h6>Dates</h6>
    <?php echo $this->__('Yes'); ?>
</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```